# Show hidden div in order

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, input

I have this code:

**[CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/crfelipe/7f3ym4hn/)**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).text();
    $('.'+a).show();
    $('.'+a).css("order", "1");
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class='1' style='display:none'><input type='text' value='1'></input>
  </div>
  <div class='2' style='display:none'><input type='text' value='2'></input>
  </div>
  <div class='3' style='display:none'><input type='text' value='3'></input>
  </div>

  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
```

I need them to be in the order in which I click the button.
I tried to use `.css('order','1')`, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It works in the snippet.

Comment: example:
if I click button 2 first, input 2 should be first,
if button 3 is the second button I click, input 3 should be the second and
if button 1 is the third to be clicked, input 1 must be the third.

Comment: 2 things. CSS classes cannot start with numbers. The `order` property needs a `flex` or `grid` layout and won't do anything without one of those.

Comment: I think of having a <select> that shows div according to the options chosen.
there may be more than 10 options, I would not like the option chosen to be in a bad location.
I chose to use the button on the question just for convenience.

Comment: @FelipeCristiano so once all the options have been selected, they're done? Can someone click after they've selected all options? For example, can they go 3, 1, 2, 3? Where the final display order (top to bottom) would be 3, 2, 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can create a wrapper and use [appendTo](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/) instead of relying on the `order` property.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var a = $(this).text();
  $('.' + a).show();
  $('.' + a).appendTo('.wrapper');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='a' style='display:none'><input type='text' value='1'>
  </div>
  <div class='b' style='display:none'><input type='text' value='2'>
  </div>
  <div class='c' style='display:none'><input type='text' value='3'>
  </div>
</div>

<button>a</button>
<button>b</button>
<button>c</button>
```

Comment: I really liked the answer, but if I need them in reverse order, what can I modify to make this code work?

Comment: @FelipeCristiano instead of `appendTo` use `prependTo`.

Comment: I used it this way:
`if($('.' + a).is(":hidden")){
   $('.' + a).appendTo('.wrapper');
}`

Comment: I can remove the `if` if I want the positions to always be updated

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/fxsa3e85/3/

```js
$( 'button' ).click(function() {

  console.log( $( ".div[style*='display: unset']" ).length );


  var a = $( this ).text();
  $( '.' + a ).css( "display", "unset" );
  $( '.' + a ).css( "order", $( ".div[style*='display: unset']" ).length + 1 );

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="orders" style="display:grid">
  <div class="div 1" style="display: none"><input type="text" value="1"></div>
  <div class="div 2" style="display: none"><input type="text" value="2"></div>
  <div class="div 3" style="display: none"><input type="text" value="3"></div>
</div>


<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```